# How to hide json object in recyclerview based on condition?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have one json array in array list I need show one object as count and one as text view, while going to filter the object I'm not able to find count view and display view, I search for hash map but it does not work, my question i can i add two array list in one recyclerview adapter one for view and one for count in same view. 
Edit: after researching about that I come to know I need to hide object if it is a match with id but I could not found to display and hide content base on condition in recyclerview any solution?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DiscussingAdapter.DiscussionView holder, int position) {
    HashMap<String, List<Result>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, List<Result>>();
    Result result = discussionsList.get(position);
    //discussionsList.get(position);

    List<Result> filterList = discussionsList.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getParentCommentID()==null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Log.d("filterList",filterList.toString());
    for (int counter = 0; counter < filterList.size(); counter++) {
        holder.tvHeader.setText(filterList.get(counter).getTitle());
        holder.tvDetail.setText(Utils.html2text(filterList.get(counter).getComment()));
        holder.tvViewReply.setText("Reply");
        holder.tvUser.setText("By " + filterList.get(counter).getAuthor().getTitle());
        String DateofReceipt = filterList.get(counter).getCreated();
        String date = DateofReceipt.split("T", 0)[0];
        String date_before = date;
        String date_after = Utils.date(date_before);
        holder.tvDate.setText(date_after);
    }

    Map<String, Integer> commentsCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Result res : discussionsList) {
        String parentCommentId = res.getParentCommentID();
        // If the Result has a parent comment
        if(parentCommentId != null) {
            // get the count for this parent comment (default to 0)
            int nbCommentsForParent = commentsCountMap.getOrDefault(parentCommentId, 0);
            // increment the count
            nbCommentsForParent++;
            // Update the Map with the new count
            commentsCountMap.put(parentCommentId, nbCommentsForParent);


        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> cCount : commentsCountMap.entrySet()){

        holder.tvViewReply.setText(String .valueOf(cCount.getValue())+" Reply");



    }}
```

**Json object generated is as below**

```
      {
      "d": {
"results": [
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "e7433825-6771-4f5e-96c7-c4d2674d7764",
      "uri": "",
      "etag": "\"2\"",
      "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
    },
    "Author": {
      "__metadata": {
        "id": "f064775c-6161-4bdb-9f4d-8bc6a898d218",
        "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
      },
      "Title": "Submitter1"
    },
    "Id": 1501,
    "ID": 1501,
    "Title": null,
    "Created": "2019-06-06T04:15:17Z",
    "ParentCommentID": "1439",
    "Comment": "<div class=\"ExternalClass8C333A77B6564A53BED74CA1BA2D2A10\">
    reply add for 009</div>",
    "CommentType": null,
    "CommentDocumentName": null,
    "AppID": "1083",
    "Role": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "e92f708f-93dc-4587-8c4f-5518ed24f360",
      "uri": "",
      "etag": "\"2\"",
      "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
    },
    "Author": {
      "__metadata": {
        "id": "209d2d9a-bb07-4064-aaa0-231ad881a80f",
        "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
      },
      "Title": "Submitter1"
    },
    "Id": 1500,
    "ID": 1500,
    "Title": null,
    "Created": "2019-06-06T04:14:55Z",
    "ParentCommentID": "1439",
    "Comment": "<div class=\"ExternalClass44B1A0BB4D314C57BEE20141BFF10491\">comment add for       009</div>",
    "CommentType": null,
    "CommentDocumentName": null,
    "AppID": "1083",
    "Role": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "ec112002-3132-4bc1-8f85-03fbd9fda11d",
      "uri": "",
      "etag": "\"2\"",
      "type": "SP.Data.InquiryDiscussionsListListItem"
    },
    "Author": {
      "__metadata": {
        "id": "6e8ecb1d-4deb-4168-a8b4-a725abf8002a",
        "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
      },
      "Title": "Sarada Devi Potti"
    },
    "Id": 1439,
    "ID": 1439,
    "Title": "Canceled",
    "Created": "2019-06-03T09:32:34Z",
    "ParentCommentID": null,
    "Comment": "<div  class=\"ExternalClass5E1BFEDC348C43719AD940E644E0E0B6\">sdaeadfasdf</div>",
    "CommentType": "Public",
    "CommentDocumentName": null,
    "AppID": "1083",
    "Role": "Budget Analyst"
    }
   ]
   }
    }
```

In Above Json response  if object is Comment I want to display content but if it is a reply I need to display count base on id match any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can  achieve this in a simple way first pass both the list to your adapter 
then return the total size

```
  @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size() + mList1.size();
}
```

Now for `onBindViewHolder` for example you want to display `mList` first then

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DiscussingAdapter.DiscussionView holder, int position) {
if(position < mList.size()){
// Load the data from mList 
holder.tvName.setText(mList.get(position).getName())
}else{
//For getting Data from secondList
holder.tvName.setText(mList1.get(position-mList.getSize()).getName())
// Now you will get data from second List

}
}
```

Comment: i need two type data not two data i need first filter array list which is dose not have parantId to to show the data and second one parrant id Data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you fully. However, In my opinion, you can create a model class and keep two variables there.

```
public class Demo {
    private int count;
    private int value;

    public Demo(int count, int value) {
        this.count = count;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, you can create an `ArrayList` of that model class and pass it to `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
ArrayList<Demo> demos = new ArrayList<>();
Demo firstObject = new Demo(1, 10);
demos.add(firstObject);
Demo secondObject = new Demo(2, 11);
demos.add(secondObject);
Demo thirdObject = new Demo(3, 12);
demos.add(thirdObject);
```

Feel free to ask if I'm not clear or anything else.

Comment: in my json response i have i need to parse tow type data in one view, for example if parranet id is null then its going to display as reply and if comment id having some id then i need to match same id then display number of object as a count i'm not adding this object into recyclerview that's why i chooses   filter.

Comment: in that case if object as comment we need to display the content if object as reply we need give count base on ParentCommentID.

Comment: In my opinion. you should parse the `json` first in the activity. Then create an `ArrayList` with the result. Then, take two `ViewHolder` in the `RecyclerView`. One for if id is matched, another for not matched. Then check it in the `onBindViewHolder` method of `RecyclerView`.